# iText : linked textField can only be change on first page

Tags: java, itext

I'm new to itext, and I need to create a pdf, with the same field on every page so that when I change the value of one of them they all change and have the same value.
So far I'm creating a `TextField` on each page, use it to get a `PdfFormField` and then I add it to a global parent `PdfFormField`. I add annotation to the parent and to the children and it's almost working the way I want except for one thing :

When I want to select the field with the mouse, I can only do it on the first page, on the others, the cursor rotate 90° and I can't select the text in the field. I can get to the needed field with tab, and changing it change all the value in the pdf as I want it to, but I can't access it with the cursor.
I checked the itext doc and search for examples/tutos, didn't find anything that helped so far
Does anyone have an idea why it does that ? Is there problem with the way I'm doing it ? At the beginning of the document I rotate it (need to be landscape) can it cause this problem ?

Thx in advance,

Edit :

```
private void addChangeableField(String fieldName, TextField textField, PdfFormField parent) throws IOException,
        DocumentException {
    PdfFormField datafield = textField.getTextField();

    datafield.setFieldName(fieldName);

    datafield.setFieldFlags(PdfFormField.FF_EDIT | PdfFormField.FF_DONOTSCROLL);
    datafield.setMKTextPosition(PdfFormField.Q_CENTER);

    parent.addKid(datafield);
    writer.addAnnotation(parent);
    writer.addAnnotation(datafield);
}
```

Here is how I add a field that can be change and modify other fields

And here is the example http://docdro.id/To19NKQ

Comment: Please share your pivotal code and probably also a link to a sample result PDF for quick inspection.

Comment: I just had a look at your PDF. On the first page you have a single copy of that field. On the second one you have two copies. On the third one there are three copies. There seems to be an issue in the code calling your `addChangeableField` method...